# Is there a standard benchmark for neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, benchmarking

I'd like to use a *standard benchmark* for neo4j, to see how my setup performes relative to others, and also *check if my installation is working correctly*. I guess this would not only require the performance test itself, but also a collection of results.

I am thinking of something along the line:

- one or two predefined datasets (e.g. random social network, dbpedia export)
- some queries

The *results* would be measured in times taken for a single query on a otherwise unused machine.

In the end I'd like to know: given the example datasets, and the example queries, I get returns in x secs, *so my setup seems to be ok* (or is y% better/worse then expected)

Comment: Such questions are vague. How do you define standard benchmark? and relative to others? To compare you need to have programmed with other technologies. And you have provided no basis to compare.

Comment: Ok, will clarify what I mean.

Comment: Well it cannot exist. A simple `java` program running standalone or as a part of long running server will perform differently. A lot of factors come in- Number of concurrent reads and rights, relationships per node, key-value pairs, transactions, locks holded etc and there cannot be **standard benchmark**. I think what you mean is a comparison of same program using neo4j vs mysql?

Comment: I don't want to compare neo4j against mysql. I'd really like to know how well my setup works, or if have some misconfiguration. So measuring predefined queries on a predefined queries should help. And the info of "running query1 on testset 1 should take 0.5 secs on average". Maybe 'standard benchmark' is the wrong word, but I hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

On the official side, there is work going on in the LDBC project, http://www.ldbc.eu/ to create standard benchmarks.

For neo4j, there are a couple of datasets but no official benchmark. What numbers do you have now?